# How to restrict search to component's field value with grails searchable plugin

Tags: grails, lucene, compass-lucene

Using grails searchable plugin, I would like to search for all products within a specific category using a query builder like:

```
Products.search {
  must(queryString(params.q))
  must(term('??????','Food'))  
}
```

Using 'category.name' returns: Failed to find mapping for alias [category] and path [category.name]

```
class Product {    
  String name
  String desc
  Category category

  static searchable = {
    category component: true
  }
}

class Category {      
  String name

  static hasMany = [products: Product]

  static searchable = true     
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do something like:

```
def results = Product.search {
  must(term('$/Product/category/name', params.categoryName))
  must(queryString(params.q))
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That works, so does 
term('Product.category.name', params.categoryName)